# Getting Error When Doing npm run build:prod of my Angular2 App

Tags: angular, typescript

My app works fine when i do a npm start .
But when trying to build using prod - npm run build:prod

It is throwing a weird error in one of the compiled ts files . I cannot get it why.

Please help

The Component file of the js file .

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';

import { CompetitionService } from '../shared/competition.service';

@Component({
  selector:'competitiontable',
  styleUrls:['table.component.css'],
  templateUrl:'table.component.html' //or use absoulte path with templateUrl:'app/competition/competition.component.html'require('./table.component.html')
})

export class TableComponent implements OnInit{

    constructor(private competitionService:CompetitionService,private route:ActivatedRoute,private router: Router) {

    }
      competitionId:string;
      competitionTeams:any;
      teamId:string;
      //groupComptetitionTeams:any;
      visibleLeague:boolean;
      visibleTournament:boolean;

    ngOnInit(){
      this.competitionId = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
      console.log("competition ID"+this.competitionId);
      this.getTeams();
    }

    getTeams(){
      this.competitionService.getTeams(this.competitionId).subscribe(teams => {
                                                                if(teams.standing){
                                                                  this.visibleLeague = true;
                                                                  this.visibleTournament = false;
                                                                  return this.competitionTeams = teams.standing;
                                                                }else{
                                                                  this.visibleLeague = false;
                                                                  this.visibleTournament = true;
                                                                  return this.competitionTeams = teams.standings;
                                                                }
      });
      //this.competitionService.getTeams(this.competitionId).subscribe(teams => (this.groupComptetitionTeams = teams.standings));


    }

    onSubmit(team:any){
      this.teamId = team._links.team.href.split('/').pop(-1);
      this.competitionService.storeTeamCrest(team.crestURI);
      this.router.navigate(['team', {id: this.teamId}]);
    }


}
```

The Error line in the ts file. Coudnt paste the whole js as it is very big

```
 detectChangesInternal(throwOnChange:boolean):void {
    const valUnwrapper:any = new import13.ValueUnwrapper();
    valUnwrapper.reset();
    const currVal_4_0_0:any = valUnwrapper.unwrap(import3.castByValue(this._pipe_keys_0_0,(<View_TableComponent0>this.parentView)._pipe_keys_0.transform)(this.parentView.context.competitionTeams)); // this is the error line
    this._NgFor_4_6.check_ngForOf(currVal_4_0_0,throwOnChange,valUnwrapper.hasWrappedValue);
    this._NgFor_4_6.ngDoCheck(this,this._anchor_4,throwOnChange);
    this._vc_4.detectChangesInNestedViews(throwOnChange);
  }
```

The error in the console when building

```
[at-loader] Checking finished with 1 errors
Error in bail mode: [at-loader] compiled\src\app\table\table.component.ngfactory.ts:530:51
    TS2346: Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.
```

Pipe

```
import { PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'keys'})
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value, args:string[]) : any {
    let keys = [];
    for (let key in value) {
      keys.push({key: key, value: value[key]});
    }
    //console.log("Keys"+keys);
    return keys;
  }
}
```

Comment: const currVal_4_0_0:any = valUnwrapper.unwrap(import3.castByValue(this._pipe_keys_0_0,(<View_TableComponent0>this.parentView)._pipe_keys_0.transform)(this.parentView.context.competitionTeams)); // this is the error line

Can you please post the Pipe you have added for this code , the error line is reffering to pipe_keys

Comment: @RahulSingh added pipes to the Code

Answer (score 0):

Seems like one of your services is expecting a value to be parsed but not getting it, maybe try to make the parameter passed optional.

Comment: @tan639 I didnot get you . If this was the case how is the app running when using npm start only when i try and build it , it gives me this error

Comment: How do we get to know which ?

Comment: maybe this would be a safer approach
 `ngOnInit(){
      this.competitionId = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
      if(this.competitionId)
      this.getTeams(this.competitionId);
      else
      this.getTeams();
    }

    getTeams(comp_id?:string){
        ....
`

Comment: I tried it but to no avail still getting the same error , i also commented tue code but still i donot know why the error is popping up.